# Progressbar spinner is not rotating

Tags: android, progress-bar

Can anyone tell me why progress bar wheel is not rotating ... I am trying to put a progress bar while downloading data from web server everything is fine till now...i am able to set the progress bar while downloading data but the problem progress bar spinner is not rotating....Below is my code for progress bar:

```
<Progressbar 
    android:id="@+id/xPBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>
```

this is the downloading code:
while executing this method i am showing the progress bar

```
    public void downloadAlerts() {
    mPBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (checkNetworkStatus(getApplicationContext()) == true) {
                String alert = con.execute(ALERTS_URL
                        );
                AlertsParser parser = new AlertsParser();
                parser.parseJson(alert);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alerts.class));
                onSuccessDownload();
            } else if (checkNetworkStatus(getApplicationContext()) == false) {
                onFailureDownload();
            }

        }
    };
    mHandler.post(r);

}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Are you downloading the data on the main thread. all the http stuff need to be done on a separate thread. incase you are downloading data in the main thread, you are blocking the ui and that is the reason your progressbar is visible but not rotating.

Comment: These are all guesses, please post code that shows how you are updating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have to put it into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  If you try to put the progress bar in your main UI thread then it won't move if you do something else in the background as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 3):

By calling

> mHandler.post(r)

you are not running the runnable in a new Thread, but instead you are posting it in the message queue - this means in the main UI thread. This causes the app to freeze while your data is downloading.

You should run either AsyncTask or new thread. For example put at the end of your Runnable r something like

> Runnable r = new Runnable() {
>
> ```
>    @Override
>     public void run() {
>         .......
>         context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>             @Override
>             public void run() {
>                 hideProgressOnSuccess_andShowData();
>             }
>         });
>     }
> ```
>
> }

and then run your Runnable r like this:

> new Thread(r).start();

With AsyncTask and using its onPreExecute and onPostExecute it can be more elegant, of course.

Greets,
Dan

Comment: Hey thanks it worked now....Thank you so muh now my spinner is rotating like a fan....wow..lol....

Comment: @Danail. Please help me in this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987880/android-progress-bar-stops-working-in-the-middle